# Echo out one value from an array

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I selected an array of product IDs and product names from the table product. I tried to echo out only one product name from the array, but all I got was the first letter of the product name. Below is my code. Thanks in advance for any tips.

```
$info1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT `productid`,`productname` FROM `$product` WHERE id  =     :id  ORDER BY `productname` ASC ");
$info1 ->bindParam(':id', $sessionid , PDO::PARAM_INT);
$info1->execute();

while ($userinfo1 = $info1->fetchobject()) {

$productid = "$userinfo1->productid";
$productname = "$userinfo1->productname";

}

echo $productname[0];
```

Comment: Read the manual on `fetch()` http://www.php.net//manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: What format do you want this in? Are you hoping to get  a 2D array?

Comment: The first letter you're seeing is `$productname[0]`. The variable `$productname` only holds a plain scalar string, and the index `[0]` on a string retrieve its first character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add brackets to the variables inside the while loop to create the array

```
while ($userinfo1 = $info1->fetchobject()) {

 $productid[] = "$userinfo1->productid";
 $productname[] = "$userinfo1->productname";

}

echo $productname[0];//this will print the first productname
```

I think is better make just 1 array of objects

```
$array=array();
while ($userinfo1 = $info1->fetchobject()) {
   $array[] = $userinfo1;
}

echo $array[0]->productname;
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing this :

```
$info1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT `productid`,`productname` FROM `$product` WHERE id  =     :id  ORDER BY `productname` ASC ");
$info1 ->bindParam(':id', $sessionid , PDO::PARAM_INT);
$info1->execute();

while ($userinfo1 = $info1->fetchobject()) {

$productid = "$userinfo1->productid";
    $productname = "$userinfo1->productname";

    }

    echo $productname[0];
```

Do this :

```
$info1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT `productid`,`productname` FROM `$product` WHERE id  =     :id  ORDER BY `productname` ASC ");
$info1 ->bindParam(':id', $sessionid , PDO::PARAM_INT);
$info1->execute();
$counter =0;
while ($userinfo1 = $info1->fetchobject()) {
$productid[] = "$userinfo1->productid";
$productname[] = "$userinfo1->productname";
echo $productid[counter];
echo $productname[counter];
counter++;
}
```

this way you'll echo out every value of the array

Answer (score 0):

You have various options at your disposal. Take your look for instance, you could create an associative array like the following:

```
$items = array();
while ($userinfo1 = $info1->fetchobject()) {
    $item = array(
        'productid' => $userinfo1->$productid,
        'productname' => $userinfo1->$productname
    );
    array_push($items, $item);
    // or you could use native
    // $uitems[] = $item;
}
```

That would give you an array (`$users`) that you could loop through and fetch for set index:

```
foreach($items as $item) {
    print_r($item); // prints the whole user item.
    //print $item['productid']; /* or even print the users product id.*/
}
```

Or simple for one item like you requested:

```
echo $items[0]['productid'];
```

---

**Alternatively:** if you'd like seperate arrays, you could do as stated in the other answers:

```
while ($userinfo1 = $info1->fetchobject()) {

 $productid[] = "$userinfo1->productid";
 $productname[] = "$userinfo1->productname";

}
```